# Python server to receive specific data from two clients on same remote device

Tags: python, sockets

I was able to set up a simple socket server and client connection between two devices, with the ability to send and receive values. My issue is with setting up the remote server to accept two clients from the same device, and differentiate the data being received by them.

Specifically, each client will be running a similar code to accept encoder/decoder values from their respective motor. My main program, attached to the server, needs to use the data from each client separately, in order to carry out the appropriate calculations. How do I differentiate the incoming signals coming from both clients?

Comment: You might want to show the actual code. With the information you are currently providing, it is not even clear what kind of socket you are using.

Comment: Will both clients be sharing the connection or creating their own connection? Are you using tcp?

Answer (score 0):

When the communication isn't heavy between clients and server, one way to do this is to have clients do a handshake to server and have the server enumerate clients and send back id's for communication.

Then the client sends it's id along with any communication it has with server in order for the server to identify it.  At least that is what I did.